# how to compare values in two MySQL queries

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I have this team page that contains a list of team members and a select list that contains the list of my friends. From the select list, you can select friends to be added to the team (members). Now, I want to ensure that friends that are already team members don't show up in the select list.

I tried the below but nothing is showing in the select list, it is supposed to show the details of one friend who is not part of the team members.

The code

```
    <form action="tmembers.php" method="post">
        <select multiple="true" name="members[]"  val id="member" class="">    
        <?php
        while($record5 = $stmt5->fetch()){    //Gets ids from my friend list
            $friends[] = $record5['id'];      //array containing ids of friends
        }
        $membersarray[] = $members['id'];     //array containing ids of team members

        foreach ($friends AS $t) {
            if (in_array($t, $membersarray)) {
               continue;            
            } 
        ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $record5['id'] ; ?>">  
            <?php echo $record5['surname'];?> <?php echo $record5['firstname'] ; ?>  
        </option>

        <?php } // end-foreach
        ?>

        </select>
        </br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send Invite" name="invite" class=""/>
   </form>
```

Comment: Please add `var_dump($friends)` and `var_dump($membersarray)` to your question

Comment: Please do as @CharlesRojas suggested. The error could be in the structure of the arrays or the type of the values or something else.

Comment: The results in the arrays show up well. Please help me check if my code is okay.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$record5` variable outside your while loop.

I'm assuming `$members['id']` is an ID that is being added to `$membersarray[]`. If it's an array itself, then you should use `$membersarray[0]` inside the `foreach`.

Try this:

```
<form action="tmembers.php" method="post">
    <select multiple="true" name="members[]"  val id="member" class="">    
    <?php
    while($record5 = $stmt5->fetch()){    //Gets ids from my friend list
        $friends[] = $record5;            //array containing ids of friends
    }
    $membersarray[] = $members['id'];     //array containing ids of team members

    foreach ($friends AS $t) {
        if (in_array($t['id'], $membersarray)) {
           continue;            
        } 
    ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $t['id'] ; ?>">  
        <?php echo $t['surname'];?> <?php echo $t['firstname'] ; ?>  
    </option>

    <?php } // end-foreach
    ?>

    </select>
    </br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Invite" name="invite" class=""/>
</form>
```